# Chrome extension callback?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first Chrome extension. I think I need to learn how to do callbacks. Bit stumped on making [history.getVisits()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#method-getVisits) be useful.

I can retrieve HistoryItems well enough, but I can't figure out how to use VisitItems in conjunction with HistoryItems.

```
chrome.history.getVisits({url:historyItemUrl}, function(visitItems){
    // I can loop through the visitItems, but...
    // how can I access the historyItemUrl from in here?
    // do I need to make a better function for the 2nd param?
});
```

I've looked at and tried many callback examples here from SO, but the JS console keeps saying something about requiring the 2nd parameter in `getVisits()` when I try and use my own callback function. I think I'm just missing the concept of callbacks, really.

Please help if you can - thanks!

Comment: Could you please add come code inside `getVisits` even if it doesn't work, it would be easier to understand what you are trying to do and in which format do you need the result. Currently it is not very clear. Is your `getVisits` inside some loop as well (are you looping through `historyItemUrl`?)

Comment: In typing up some additional code here to explain this better, I had an epiphany and have changed some of the logic elsewhere in the script. I'm still not sure where I stand on callbacks but I've fixed my problem via saving history URLs to a global array elsewhere and then looping `getVisits()` for each item in the array, popping them off once processed. Thank you for looking anyhow :) Can probably close this now.

Comment: Good to hear. If you are still interested in knowing what was the problem with callbacks you can post your original code, I am pretty sure you are dealing with a common problem "callbacks inside a loop", but need to see the code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you added this in manifest file : "permissions": [ ..., "history", ... ]

Then you can access the historyItemUrl very simple:

```
var historyItemUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
chrome.history.getVisits({url:historyItemUrl}, function(visitItems){
    alert(historyItemUrl); // here you can access it.
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's good to know. Thanks. Thought only `visitItems` was passed through!